# what is the use of the migrate module UI in drupal 7

Tags: 7

Guys do i still have to code object oriented coding when i use the migrate module in drupal 7? like this one example here.

http://miss-hana.com/migrate-contents-from-drupal-6-to-drupal-7-using-migrate-2/

if so, then what's the use of the UI for migrate module provided in drupal 7? i cant post a screenshot of the UI i nee 10 reputation for that. But it is in the 3rd tab in the content page.

if i still have to code, anyone can guide me to a very good tutorial or video on how to code this step by step. Because im not into object-oriented programming. :(

Answer (score 1):

The UI just acts as a display for the mappings that you create, it also tells you how many nodes have been imported and how man haven't so you can manually do it.

There is lots of documentation on the drupal website here http://drupal.org/migrate and the example migrations are worth a look.

To migrate from drupal 6 to 7 I used created an xml view in drupal 6 and then created my mappings to use that in Drupal 7.

Cheers

Comment: how about i want to migrate a non drupal site to a drupal 7 site? can i use this module too? or this is only designed to migrate from drupal to drupal?

Comment: Yes, You can use the migrate module for every kind of scenario